# Jspirit for shipping industry

Tags: jsprit

We are in shipping industry which has three modes of transport (viz) door to door, intermodal and ocean trunk. We are evaluating different options to optimize our network so as to maximize our yield and in this regard, we wanted to check any one had used jspirit for container transportation especially with ocean legs? If yes, any insight will speed up our evaluation ( jspirit is one option).

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

To help you with your evaluation, jsprit cannot be used to optimize networks. Network optimization is a level above, more strategical rather than tactical and operational. However, once you optimized your network, you can use jsprit to optimize your vehicle routes, e.g. on the last mile or on your main legs etc. Furthermore, whether jsprit fits your needs depends on your requirements or the constraints of your problem. There are a number of constraints you can model with jsprit (e.g. time windows, multiple vehicle dimensions and more). However, there are also constraints you cannot easily model with jsprit yet, but which might be of high importance for you, e.g. driver breaks. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Stefan, I am getting there. Looks to me jspirit is route optimization engine. Will it also give route options? For example my input is two points A and B and zero constraints and expected output is top 10 routes in the ascending order of cost.

Comment: You mean you have two points A and B and want to calculate the shortest path between these points? And not only one path, but the 10 best ones? Well, then you need to look for a shortest path calculator rather than a vehicle router ... a good option her is Graphhopper.

Comment: Thanks Stefan, I will look at graph hopper